# How do i code a link in a comment if the link is to an ftp:// site?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I just tried to include a link in a comment (to question 13831 -- would appreciate it if someone fixes it), and failed miserably to get it to format correctly.  the link is to a document in an `ftp://...` area, not `http://...` I tried to follow the help suggestion, but that didn't improve anything.

On earlier posts or comments the html formula `<a href="...">...</a>` appeared to work (although i noticed soon after that someone had edited it but i couldn't see the underlying code).  i haven't checked the faq about this just now, but i don't remember seeing anything useful there.  the ["Code and Preformatted Text"](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page **does** say that the html syntax can be used, as does the "How to Format" box on the "ask question" page.

Are the conventions for coding in comments different than those for questions?

Help, please.

Comment: [Example](ftp://example.org) `[Example](ftp://example.org)`

Comment: You just can't use _any_ HTML tags in comments, just markdown. And as TH observes in his answer, HTML entities are also not supported in comments.

Comment: @Martin: But it's _barbaba beeton_ `:-)`

Comment: @Martin: You noticed, [but didn't understand](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb15-1/tb42arseneau.pdf) `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: Knuth's little joke! I was just wondering what that was on my [blog](http://texhacks.blogspot.com/2011/03/knuth-quote-v.html)! (Okay, that wasn't your point, but still!)

Comment: @TH: What a coicidence! As to what his joke is, it surely is that _one_ page in that chapter has a different running head. I never noticed that, and I wonder how many did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Example](ftp://example.org) produced by: `[Example](ftp://example.org)`

They seem to be the same.

I've noticed that HTML that works in answers doesn't always work in comments. For example *ε*-TeX (`_&epsilon;_-TeX`) doesn't work.